# Apollo federation throws error: marked @external but is not defined on the base service of

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

i'm using apollo federation and meet with error, when trying to make something similar to computed fields (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/entities/#extending-an-entity-with-computed-fields-advanced):

```
Error: A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found:client-api-gateway_1
[Payments MS] User.parentId -> marked @external but parentId is not defined on the base service of User (Users MS)
```

I have two services: `Users` and `Payments`. In `users` service i store information about users, and in `payments` information about payments connected to user.

`Users` service graph:

```
type User @key(fields: "id") {
        id: Int!
        name: String!
        surname: String!
        type: USER_TYPE!
        parentId: Int
    }
```

`Payments` service graph:

```
type UserSubscriptionInfo {
     nextChargeAmount: Int
     ......etc
}

extend type User @key(fields: "id") {
     id: Int! @external
     parentId: Int @external
     subscription: UserSubscriptionInfo @requires(fields: "parentId")
}
```

Based on `parentId` from User type i would like to get subscription, by extending `User` type.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Can you provide me a different solution if u have? Because both my graphql schemas are in same gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you put both graphql schemas in the same gateway. In my app there was 2 different gateways and i put them in 2 different gateways. Above code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check also if the extended class has `@GqlKey('id')` in its class

For example :

```
@ObjectType({
  description: 'Extended Class',
})
@GqlKey('id') // <- Check if this extention exist 
export class ClassName{
  @Field(() => ID)
  @Expose()
  id: string;
  ...
}
```